# Removing lines when drawing multiple arcs in a row in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, lines

So I'm trying to draw 8 random circles (Or bubbles as I call them in this case) on the screen for a simple project I'm making. I want to make it so that I can show the bubbles, but there are lines connecting each bubble at its startAngle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
     <title>Image</title>
</head>

<body>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
     <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
     <script>
         var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

         var height = canvas.height;
         var width = canvas.width;


         ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);


         var bubbles = [];

         var Bubble = function () {
             this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
             this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
             this.xspeed = 5;
             this.yspeed = 5;
         };

         for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             bubbles[i] = new Bubble();
         };

         Bubble.prototype.draw = function () {
             for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
             ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
             ctx.arc(bubbles[i].x, bubbles[i].y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
             }
         };

         setInterval(function () {
             for (var i = 0; i < bubbles.length; i++) {
                 ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
                 bubbles[i].draw();
                 ctx.stroke();
             }
         }, 30);





     </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Basically, I've made 8 Bubble objects, then I've drawn an arc at their x and y (random) position, but it shows lines connecting them like so:

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti7i3.png)

When you run the code, it randomly generates 8 different locations and draws 8 arcs at their location, but it shows the lines that connect them. Is there a way to hide or get rid of these lines? I've tried to clear the canvas after each draw, but that hides the entire thing including the circle. I've been searching for most of the day and I couldn't find an answer to my specific problem. The answer is probably obvious, but I couldn't seem to find the solution due to my inexperience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `ctx.beginPath()` before `arc()` to draw separate entities?

Comment: Thank you. At first adding ctx.beginPath() didn't work, but then I figured it out and put ctx.stroke() after the arc() line, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Nice on.

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.arc()` creates an `ctx.lineTo()` between the last coordinates of the current path, and the first position of the arc.

So to avoid it, you can simply manually call `moveTo()` to lift the drawing pen to the first position of the arc.

This way, you can draw multiple arcs in the same Path and in the same `stroke` call (which becomes interesting when you draw a lot of arcs)

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
w = c.width,
h = c.height;

ctx.beginPath(); // call it once
for(let i = 0; i<100; i++){
  let rad = Math.random()*20 + 5
  let posX = rad + Math.random() * (w - rad *2);
  let posY = rad + Math.random() * (h - rad *2); 
  // our arc will start at 3 o'clock
  ctx.moveTo(posX + rad, posY); // so simply add 'rad' to the centerX
  ctx.arc(posX, posY, rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
  }
ctx.stroke(); // call it once
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500"></canvas>
```